# Update fields in Custom Object (Latest Feedback) when related event feedback is updated

Tags: trigger, custom-object

This is only the 2nd trigger I've attempted to write, and it's making me nuts. I have two custom objects: Latest Feedback (child of Feedback(Event)).

I want my trigger to write back one fields from the Latest Activity to its related Feedback, Status and Feedback is not Null.

An After Insert trigger on Status that writes back to Tasks, and an After Update trigger on Feedback that waits for a related Latest Feedback to be created.

```
trigger change_feedback on Task (after insert, after update) { 
    Set accountSet = new Set();

    List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();    
    //variable to hold account id & task feedback
    Map<Id,String> accntValMap = new Map<Id,String>();

    //get task Account id & Feedback for tasks with Status "Completed"
    for(Task t : trigger.new){
        if(t.Status == 'Completed') {
            accntValMap.put(t.whatId,t.FEEDBACK__C); 
        }    
    }

    //query the accounts that we need to update
    List<Account> acctsToUpdate = [Select Id from Account where id in :accntValMap.keySet()];

    //now use the map variable to update the account field
    for(Account acc : acctsToUpdate){
        acc.Feedback__c = accntValMap.get(acc.Id);
    }

    //update the accounts back to database
    update acctsToUpdate;
}
```

An After Insert trigger on Feedback that writes back to Event, and an After Update trigger on Feedback that waits for a related Latest Feedback to be created.

```
trigger change_feedbackOnEvent on Event  (after insert, after update)  {
     Set<String> accountSet = new Set<String>();

     List<Event> events = [select Id,Whatid,FEEDBACK__C from Event where
     id in :trigger.newMap.keySet()];
     List<string> accIds = new List<string>();    
     //variable to hold account id & task feedback
     Map<Id,String> accntValMap = new Map<Id,String>();

     //get task Account id & Feedback for tasks with Status "Comnpleted"
     for(Event e : trigger.new){
        if(e.Feedback != '') {
          accIds.add(e.whatId);
        accntValMap.put(e.whatId,e.FEEDBACK__C); 
        }    
     }

      //query the accounts that we need to update
     List<Account> acctsToUpdate = [Select Id from Account where id in
     :accntValMap.keySet()];

     //now use the map variable to update the account field
    for(Account acc : acctsToUpdate){
     acc.Feedback__c = accntValMap.get(acc.Id);
    }

    //update the accounts back to database
    update acctsToUpdate;
}
```

Both triggers are working fine but after created event that showing the task feedback in latest feedback field(custom field). I want the latest feedback of event.

Comment: You should use _Feedback__c_ instead of _Feedback_ as I believe feedback is a custom field

Comment: event feedback is not custom field

Comment: i want to update latest feedback based on feedback field of task and event....

Comment: I have two stage ie task and event. My Custom field is "Latest Feedback" once customer create task means i fetch the feedback from task based on the "status" is completed and if the customer is reach event means same as above. My trigger is working fine but is not updated the event feedback it is show only task feedback

Answer (score 1):

Not all Events and Task are going to be related to Account, so the first thing you need to do is collect the WhatIds, not run a query. You've made the assumption that all of the WhatIds will be Account Ids. They could be related to Opportunity, Campaigns, or something else.

As I understand your code, `Feeback__c` is a field on Accounts and also a custom field on `Event` as well as `Task`. If it's not, you'll want to query the custom object that's perhaps a lookup or a Detail record related to Activities once you know you have a set of WhatIds that isn't empty which are all Account Ids that will have Feedback.

Below is some example code using `Event` that I believe will show you how to do what you want.

```
trigger change_feedbackOnEvent on Event  (after insert, after update)  {

     Set<Id>Wids = new set<id>();
     Map<Id,String>accntValMap = new Map<Id,String>();

     // collect What Ids
     // We know that Account Ids start with '001'
     for(Event e : trigger.new){
        if(string.valueOf(e.WhatId).startsWith('001') == true && string.isEmpty(e.FEEDBACK__C) == false){
           Wids.add(e.WhatId);
           accntValMap.put(e.whatId,e.FEEDBACK__C);
        }
     }

     List<Account>AcctsUp = new List<Account>();    

     for(Id aId : WIds ){
        Account a = new Account(Id = aId);
        a.Feedback__c = accntValMap.get(aId);      

        AcctsUp.add(a);
    }

    //update the accounts back to database
    update AcctsUp;

}
```

This pattern should work for both Events and Tasks once you adjust the `If` test condition.

Comment: i got this error   Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: isEmpty(String) at line 37 column 66

Comment: I have two stage ie  task and event. My Custom field is "Latest Feedback" once customer create task means i fetch the feedback from task based on the "status" is completed  and if the customer is reach event means same as above. My trigger is working fine but is not updated the event feedback it is show only task feedback.

Comment: Have corrected code. Should have been `string.isEmpty(e.FEEDBACK__C)`, assuming the Feedback is in the event object.

Comment: But is not working same error i getting

Comment: What kind of field is `FEEDBACK__c`? Is it a rich text area field of some kind instead of a regular text field? If so, you may need to do something else as it behaves differently. Otherwise, you may need to put `Boolean Result = String.isEmpty(e.FEEDBACK__c);` before on the line ahead of your `If` statement, then change the related part of your `if` statement clause to `&& Result == false)`.

Comment: can you explain briefly

Comment: isEmpy() is a boolean string method that tests for null, blank, `''`, etc, all in one call. Your original code was only testing for `''`. A RTF can sometimes behave differently than a string and because of formatting needs to be tested for more than just `''`. But long text areas and RTF Areas sometimes need to be treated differently. Assigning the results of the method to Boolean result can often fix those issues allowing the complex operation to properly compile so that in the if statement it's easily a true/false test.

Comment: but if statement is not working i got error. 
i got this error Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: isEmpty(String) at line

Comment: You should have the following two lines in this order:  `Boolean Result = String.isEmpty(e.FEEDBACK__c);` then `if(string.valueOf(e.WhatId).startsWith('001') == true && Result  == false){` If that isn't working, what kind of field is `FEEDBACK__c`??

Comment: I change Trigger it get value and show it on activity history but it is not reflect to latest feedback. It's showing only task feedback only.

Comment: Trigger change_feedbackOnEvent on Event  (after insert, after update){
    Map<Id, List<Event>> whatIds = new Map<Id, List<Event>>{};                                          For (Event e : trigger.new){
        If(e.WhatId == null || e.What.Type != 'Account'){
            continue;
        }                                                                                                                                         if(whatIds.get(e.WhatId) == null){
            whatIds.put(e.whatId, new list<Event>());
        }
        whatIds.get(e.WhatId).add(e);
    }

Comment: For (Account a : [Select Id from Account where Id in :whatIDs.keySet()]){
        For(Event e : whatIds.get(a.id)){
            e.Feedback__c= a.Feedback__c;
           // e.yourCustomPostCodeField = a.BillingPostalCode;
        }
    }
}

Comment: `If(e.WhatId == null || e.What.Type != 'Account')` makes no sense to me. First, there is no `What.Type` only a WhatId, you can't go deeper than that. 2nd, I thought you wanted the type to be = to Account, meaning first 3 digits = '001'. I suggest you  add debug statements ahead of this for the `trigger.new.WhatId` value and `getType(trigger.new.whatId)` or `type.equals(trigger.new.whatId)` (not certain on correct syntax) and I think you'll see more of what I mean.

Comment: hi crmprodev,  Feedback__c is not custom field Latest feedback is the custom field on Account. In the custom field on the account page i need update based on the  task i already done. once task is completed means it is no more. but event will live so i need the update feedback from feedback   column on event. But it does not fetch the value from event....

Comment: I don't understand Feedback__c NOT being a custom field. Your code shows it as being a custom field on both Account and on Event. I can't help you further. Ask a new question showing your latest code, state the relationships between the different objects and state very clearly what you want to accomplish; including the objects you want to ultimately transfer the info FROM and TO. I'm too confused by your comments to know exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, sorry for confusion. I have the Custom field on Account page called as "Latest Feedback".I want to show latest change of the lead. There is two condition one is task completion and another one is event. Once task completed then only  i created the event. But after create the event it does not show the latest feedback of event. I want to show the latest feedback.

Comment: Then in the code above, where it says `a.Feedback__c = accntValMap.get(aId);`, change the line to `a.Latest_Feedback__c = accntValMap.get(aId);` or whatever the API name is for the `Account 'Latest Feedback'` field. If there's some kind of sequencing involved between Task and Event, again, you'll need to ask a new question. I can't assist you further with this one.